# UDP packet re-ordering in linux

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, packet, userspace

I understand that UDP does not guarantee order of packets, but that is at Transport layer.
Does the Linux kernel guarantee ordered UDP packets to user space programs ?
I read that services like DNS and DHCP use UDP and they have daemons running in user
space for that.
If Linux does not provide ordered UDP packets to user space then how do services like
DNS and DHCP work reliably ?

Thanks

Comment: How could it? There's nothing in a UDP packet that defines the order.

Comment: DNS and DHCP only involve one request and response. There's nothing to order.

Comment: UDP applications that need packet order do it in the application layer. Take a look at TFTP for example, it has sequence numbers in the packets.